# Losing image src in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having some problems with Rails and I hope someone can help me 
The problem is this, I have a menu in my application.html.erb:

```
<div class="menuColor">
<nav>
  <ul class="menu"> 

    <% if current_user %>  


      <li class="options">
        <li >
          <%= link_to "Orchestras", :orchestras %>
        </li>
        <li class="nota">
          <img src="../images/nota1.png" alt="nota1" width="35" height="35">
        </li>
      </li>
      <li class="options">
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Conductors", :conductors %> 
        </li>
        <li class="nota">
          <img src="../images/nota2.png" alt="nota1" width="35" height="35">
        </li>
      </li>
      <li class="options">
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Instruments", :instruments %> 
        </li>
        <li class="nota">
          <img src="../images/nota3.png" alt="nota1" width="35" height="35">
        </li>
      </li>
      <li class="options">
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Integrants", :integrants %> 
        </li>
        <li class="nota">
          <img src="../images/nota4.png" alt="nota1" width="35" height="35">
        </li>
      </li>
      <% if current_user.auth == "admin" %>
        <li class="options">
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Users", :users %>
          </li>
          <li class="nota">
            <img src="../images/nota5.png" alt="nota1" width="35" height="35">
          </li>
        </li>
      <% end %>

       <li class="options">
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Log out", log_out_path %> </li>
        </li>
        <li class="nota">
          <img src="../images/logout.png" alt="nota1" width="35" height="35">
        </li>
       <li class="user"> Logged in as <%= current_user.email %></li>
    <% else %>  
      <li><%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %></li>   
      <li><%= link_to "Log in", log_in_path %>  </li>
    <% end %>
```

Within it as can be seen I have a picture, but when you click the edit button on the page:

```
<tbody>
  <% @orchestras.each do |orchestra| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="um"><%= orchestra.name %></td>
      <td class="dois"><%= orchestra.city %></td>
      <td class="dois"><%= @search = Conductor.find(:all,:conditions => {:id => orchestra.conductor_id})
              if(@search.first!=nil)
                @search.first.name 
              else
                @search=''
              end
          %>
      </td>
      <td class="botao"><%= button_to 'Show', orchestra,:class => "button", :method=>"get"  %></td>
      <%if(@current_user.auth=="admin")%>
        <td class="botao"><%= button_to 'Edit', edit_orchestra_path(orchestra),:class => "button", :method =>"get" %></td>
        <td class="botao"><%= button_to 'Destroy', orchestra,:class => "button", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %></td>
      <%end%>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

He loses the image path, and this only happens in the edit buttons of views, if someone can shed some light on what is happening I would be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative paths to display your pictures.

You should use an img_tag instead, which will generate the right path for you.

```
<%= image_tag 'nota2.png', size: '35', alt: 'nota2' %>
```

I suggest you read about [rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks man, it's work , I think it's not img_tag but image_tag, but thanks for the help ;)